# how to compare string to array of files and use the match

Tags: javascript, node.js

my code -

```
const products = await ProductDB.find({
      category: +req.query.category!,
      gender: +req.query.gender!,
    });
   
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../images');
fs.readdir(directoryPath, (e, images) => {
  if (e) { ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.error(`<getProducts>: 'Unable to scan directory: ' + ${e}`) } 
  images.forEach((image) => {
    products.forEach((product) => {
      if (product.imageFileName === image) {
        console.log(image);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

my images folder -

[image]

I am getting from DB a string that represent the file by name, for every file name there is an image, i want to find the file and send it to the client by the file name i am getting, and the upper mention code does not work, how can i do that?

Comment: "code does now work" -> What exactly are you asking, is your code working or not, what do you actually want help with?

Comment: @Matriarx my code does not work, how can i achive what i have asked in the Q

Comment: @Matriarx sorry i typed now. edited.

Comment: Why exactly is your code not working, are you getting any errors? Also are you trying to send one file or all of them to the client?

Comment: @Matriarx i am getting products by gender and category, it might be 1 or more. and i need to send the client the image of the product for displaying in the website.

i saved in the DB the products image file name only, and i want to compare the file name with the images folder.

right now the loops does not work, i think i might have a scope problem but i cant understand.

i am not getting errors.

Comment: 1. Make sure that you're actually getting the products from the database.  2. Make sure that you're actually getting the images from the readdir.  3. Then try and figure out if it's the loops.  Unfortunately I can't help you much because I have no idea why you say it isn't working and without knowing if you're getting any errors or "why" it isn't working I have no idea what you expect should happen and what's happening.

Comment: @Matriarx i know i am getting the data and i know i am getting the images.

i need to the the images folder array, and compare with the image file name, if there is a match i want to extract the image file.

how would you suggest to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the conversation in comments, if the only thing you need is to get the files (once you already have the filenames), then you can use:

```
const file = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, filename)))
```

To get the file.  For this you'll have to loop through each filename you have and it will execute in serial, which might not be the best approach.

You can also use:

```
const getImages = async () => {
  const products = // get your products like you did
  const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../images')

  return await Promise.all(products.map((product) => fs.readFile(directoryPath + product.image))
}
```

However that only solves part of your problem, since you mentioned that you want to send multiple files to the client (I think), I don't know of any way you can send multiple files at once, only 1 file per request.  So if you're using something like express then this will be your best option:

```
export const getFile = async (request, response) => {
  const product = // get product based on request variables, single product

  const file = fs.readFileSync(filepath, filename)

  response.sendFile(file)
}
```

If you need to send all the files at once to your client then then only thing I can think of is that you'll need to download some npm package that's able to zip your files for you so the client can download the zip.